# Root and local versions of the same module installed. How to use one over the other?

Tags: python

I have a Python module installed in a system, both in the overall root path (the one you get when you do `python setup.py install`) and in my home folder (the one you get when you do `python setup.py install --user`).

The reason I did this was that I have no root access to this system, and I needed to install a the same module with a different configuration.

I have two questions.

(1) How do I know which version of the module I'm running? The user or the root version?

(2) How do I tell python to use one over the other? That is, when I do a `import module`, I want it to use the `user` version instead of the `root` version. Is there a way to make this permanent?

(3) Is there a way to specify the import path? That is, instead of `import module`, is there a `import path/to/module` sort of command that I can use to import one version over the other? However, I would still like to access to the module components with the usual syntax `module.func()`

Comment: `import module` `module.__file__` to get the location,

Comment: You'll probably also have to play with `sys.path` - that contains the order that Python will look for imports

Comment: @PadraicCunningham That solves question (1).

Comment: @becko, just make sure you have the one you require closer to the front of your path, `sys.path.insert(1,path_to)`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham There is more than one path variable (I know of `sys.path` and `$PYTHONPATH`. Which one should I use? And how can I modify `sys.path`? Is there a way to make the change permanent?

Comment: just insert to the front of your path as per my comment, that way you are guaranteed to get the one you want

Comment: @PadraicCunningham +1 Do you mind posting an answer with the steps I have to follow? Then I can accept it.